# How to create a branch without checking the branch out?

Tags: git

With the following command, I create a branch and check `my_new_branch` out immediately:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

How to create a branch without switching to that new branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git branch my_new_branch`

[From the docs:](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

> Note that this will create the new branch, but it will not switch the
>   working tree to it;